# Post web service to upload pdf file

Tags: php, ios, pdf

I have made a script in php to upload pdf file on server from iOS application but I don't understand why it says undefined index pdfFile please let me know if you catch my mistake

Here is my iOS code

```
 Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

          //  multipartFormData.append(pdfUrl!, withName: "pdfFile")

            let pdfData = NSData(contentsOf: pdfUrl!)
            print((pdfData as? Data)!)
            multipartFormData.append((pdfData as? Data)!, withName: "pdfFile", mimeType: "application/pdf")


        },
        to: "http://www.webservice.pixsterstudio.com/uploadpdf.php",
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, , ):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    print(response.result)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

Here is my PHP  web service script:- uploadpdf.php

```
  <?php

if ($_FILES['pdfFile']['type'] == "application/pdf") {
    $source_file = $_FILES['pdfFile']['tmp_name'];
    $dest_file = "webservice.pixsterstudio.com/upload/".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name'];

    if (file_exists($dest_file)) {
        print "The file name already exists!!";
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file( $source_file, $dest_file )
        or die ("Error!!");
        if($_FILES['pdfFile']['error'] == 0) {
            $Return['status'] = 'true';
            $Return['message'] = "Pdf file uploaded successfully!";
            //print "Pdf file uploaded successfully!";
            //print "<b><u>Details : </u></b><br/>";
            //print "File Name : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name']."<br.>"."<br/>";
        //  print "File Size : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['size']." bytes"."<br/>";
        //  print "File location : upload/".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name']."<br/>";



        }
    }
}
else {
    if ( $_FILES['pdfFile']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
            $Return['status'] = 'false';
            $Return['message'] = "Pdf file not uploaded !";
        //print "Error occured while uploading file : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name']."<br/>";
        //print "Invalid  file extension, should be pdf !!"."<br/>";
        //print "Error Code : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['error']."<br/>";
    }
}
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo  json_encode($Return);

 ?>
```

Comment: Is that the actual code of `uploadpdf.php`? I see errors relating to lines that are blank

Comment: yes this is the actual code of uploadpdf.php

Comment: @ Ram Raider where is the error please let me know

Comment: I see errors reporting lines 6, 31 & 39. I got the same message when I tried posting a pdf from my local machine though it shows lines 9, 34 & 42

Comment: yes the same error undefined pdfFile right?

Comment: It was, but now I see nothing - just a blank white page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I wait for the coffee to kick in I quickly wrote this - it follows how I would usually handle file uploads - hope it might be useful.

```
$fieldname = 'pdfFile';
$targetdir = 'webservice.pixsterstudio.com/upload/';
$desiredtype = 'application/pdf';
$return=array(
    'status'    =>    'false',
    'message'    =>    'Pdf file not uploaded!'
);

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_FILES[ $fieldname ] ) ){
    try{

        $obj = (object)$_FILES[ $fieldname ];
        $name = $obj->name;
        $size = $obj->size;
        $tmp  = $obj->tmp_name;
        $type = $obj->type;
        $error= $obj->error;




        if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && $type == $desiredtype ){

            $destination = $targetdir . $name;

            if( file_exists( $destination ) ){

                $return['status']='false';
                $return['message']='File already exists!';
                $return['line']=__LINE__;

                clearstatcache();

            } else {

                $res = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $destination );
                $return['status']=$res ? 'true' : false;
                $return['message']=$res ? 'Pdf file uploaded successfully!' : 'Moving the file failed!';

            }

        } else {
            $return['status']='false';
            $return['message']='File upload error!';
            $return['line']=__LINE__;
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
            $return['status']='false';
            $return['message']=$e->getMessage();
            $return['line']=__LINE__;
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    exit( json_encode( $return ) );

} else {
    exit( header( 'HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed',true, 405 ) );
}
```

Using the following form I now receive a json message saying the upload failed...

```
    <form method='post' action='http://www.webservice.pixsterstudio.com/uploadpdf.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h1>Upload PDF to WebService</h1>
        <input type='file' name='pdfFile' />
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form> 

{"status":"false","message":"Pdf file not uploaded!"}
```

Comment: Raider it say 405 Method not allowed

Comment: Is the IOS application sendning the data via POST?

Comment: yes Ram my iOS application is sending file via post method

Comment: Also, with traditional web form based uploads the form `enctype` must be set to `multipart/form-data` - perhaps you need to set that header??

Comment: I had made a mistake in the code above - I had tried writing responses to the wrong array - it should have been the `$return` array but I was using `$result`... tested locally and it seems to work now - sorry for the error

Comment: @ Ram still it says 405 method not allowed

Comment: I just tried posting the local form to the live site and I got `{"status":"false","message":"Pdf file uploaded successfully!"}`

Comment: but i want it to send file from iOS and this is not allowing me to send it says 405 method not allowed

Comment: But if you check and find there is a new PDF file in the target directory you know that the upload mechanism works and therefore the problem must lie in the IOS code - so perhaps the IOS code shown by @pawan sen  might be of service??

Answer (score 0):

lets check your code your mistake file mime type.
check file type in php take [mimetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) file upload.

> every upload file mime type something different

```
if ($_FILES['pdfFile']['type'] == "pdf") {

}
```

replace your php file type check line see above.
this code check every pdf mimetype file upload.

> below here my ios code
>   here is my code i am not getting any type of error.

```
func callPostWithMultipartService(urlString: String, param : [String: AnyObject]?, fileData : NSData,  completion: (result: String, data : AnyObject) -> Void)
{

    upload(.POST, urlString, multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

        MultipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: fileData, name: "filepdf", fileName: "file.pdf", mimeType: "application/pdf")
        for (key, value) in param! {
            MultipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }
        }
```

Comment: dear pawan it doesn't helped me...no change still the error undefined index occurs.

Comment: @ali saiyad if you does not select file getting undefined index error ,Please before upload file check isset condition (isset($_FILES['pdfFile']) && !empty($_FILES['pdfFile'])) and after upload file.

Comment: i tried that but isset condition does not work for iOS what shall i do?

Comment: you would use `isset` in the php code rather than the `ios` ode

Comment: yes buddy I tried using in php and the response go blank no error and no result.